# Как добавить данные в связанные таблицы?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть две таблицы. В них нужно внести из `TextBox` данные:

```
class PersonData
{        
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhone  { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }

    Person person = new Person();
    Phones phones = new Phones();

    public PersonData(string firstName, string lastName, string workPhone, string homePhone)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        WorkPhone = workPhone;
        HomePhone = homePhone;
    }

    public void InsertData()
    {
        NoteBookDataContext noteBook = new NoteBookDataContext();
        Person person = new Person();
        Phones phones = new Phones();

        person.FirstName = FirstName;
        person.LastName = LastName;
        phones.HomePhone = HomePhone;
        phones.WorkPhone = WorkPhone;

        noteBook.Person.InsertOnSubmit(person);
        noteBook.Phones.InsertOnSubmit(phones);
        noteBook.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

На кнопку повесил обработчик:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{          
    PersonData personData = new PersonData(TbFirstname.Text, TbLastName.Text, TbWorkPhone.Text, TbHomePhone.Text);
    personData.InsertData();
}
```

Выдает вот такое исключение:

> Дополнительные сведения: Конфликт инструкции INSERT с ограничением
>   FOREIGN KEY "FK_Phones_Person". Конфликт произошел в базе данных
>   "NoteBookTest", таблица "dbo.Person", column 'id'.

Comment: Дополнительные сведения: Конфликт инструкции INSERT с ограничением FOREIGN KEY "FK_Phones_Person". Конфликт произошел в базе данных "NoteBookTest", таблица "dbo.Person", column 'id'.

Comment: выдает вот такое исключение

Comment: предполагаю ошибка связана с тем что у Вас происходит не согласованность данных. фактически запись в бд попадает после сабмита. т.е. сначала сабмит в персон потом вставка в телефоны. а что бы все было коректно необходимо использовать транзакции

Answer (score 1):

Так где в вашей модели связи между таблицами-то? Добавьте поля для связи.

Как делать связанные таблицы, пишется в любом учебнике по EF (вы же его используете?)

Comment: нет! я использую Linq to SQL

Comment: А, точно. Но там все очень похоже происходит. Просто добавьте ассоциацию между сущностями в дизайнере модели - и установите ее при вставке.

Comment: дак у меня добавлено вроде!  NoteBook.dbml вот этот файл!  вы это имеете ввиду??? тогда  NoteBookDataContext noteBook = new NoteBookDataContext(); я б не смог так сделать если бы этого не было бы

Comment: Нет, я имею в виду вот это: `person.Phones.Add(phone)` - или вот это: `phone.Person = person`.

Comment: Такая связь между сущностями в EF называется Relation (отношение) - а в Linq2Sql - Assotiation.

Comment: public void InsertData()
        {
            NoteBookDataContext noteBook = new NoteBookDataContext();
            Person person = new Person();
            Phones phones = new Phones();

            person.FirstName = FirstName;
            person.LastName = LastName;
            phones.HomePhone = HomePhone;
            phones.WorkPhone = WorkPhone;

           
            phones.Person = person;

            noteBook.Person.InsertOnSubmit(person);
            noteBook.Phones.InsertOnSubmit(phones);
            noteBook.SubmitChanges();
        }

Comment: Если уже есть phones.Person = person; то можно оставить только noteBook.Phones.InsertOnSubmit(phones);